# Dask doesn't clean up context in docker container

Tags: docker, dask, dask-distributed

We have a Dask pipeline in which we basically use a `LocalCluster` as a process pool. i.e. we start the cluster with `LocalCluster(processes=True, threads_per_worker=1)`. Like so:

```
dask_cluster = LocalCluster(processes=True, threads_per_worker=1)
    with Client(dask_cluster) as dask_client:
        exit_code = run_processing(input_file, dask_client, db_state).value
```

Our workflow and task parallelization works great when run locally. However when we copy the code into a Docker container (centos based), the processing completes and we *sometimes* get the following error as the container exits:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):^M
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib64/python3.6/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 240, in _feed^M
    send_bytes(obj)^M
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib64/python3.6/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 200, in send_bytes^M
    self._send_bytes(m[offset:offset + size])^M
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib64/python3.6/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 404, in _send_bytes^M
    self._send(header + buf)^M
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib64/python3.6/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 368, in _send^M
    n = write(self._handle, buf)^M
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe^M
```

Furthermore, we get multiple instances of this error which makes me think that the error is coming from abandoned worker processes. Our current working theory is that this is related somehow to the ["Docker zombie reaping problem"](https://blog.phusion.nl/2015/01/20/docker-and-the-pid-1-zombie-reaping-problem/) but we don't know how to fix it without starting from a completely different docker image and we don't want to do that.

Is there a way to fix this using only Dask cluster/client cleanup methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create the cluster as a context manager.  It is actually the thing that launches processes, not the Client.

```
with LocalCluster(...):
    ...
```

Comment: Well... that's embarrassing. I can't believe the solution was this trivial. Maybe this will help someone else out there.

Comment: Indeed.  Thank you for asking embarrassing questions on Stack Overflow.  That is what it is here for :)